# Editing Dynamics 365 SiteMap with XrmToolBox

Tags: dynamics-crm, customization, sitemap, xrmtoolbox

I'm trying to edit the SiteMap on my Dynamics 365 online instance. For that I've used the XrmToolBox. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

I would like to add a new AREA as you can see at the bottom (NEW AREA) but nothing appears. Also I have some difficulties to understand how to SiteMap works now because of the  clear separation between Sales and Customer Service Apps.
It seems like there are two site maps. 
I would like to show the new AREA on the SALES Part next to HELP tile.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I'm assuming you've clicked the Update Site Map button?

Comment: Yes, of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out how it works. The newly added area is showing only in the ***Dynamics 365 - custom*** part of the left side menu, and not in Sales or Customer Service.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is Dynamics Sales Apps which has a different sitemap other than the default sitemap. Be sure to select the correct sitemap when you load a sitemap from the xrmtoolbox sitemap editor.
That should solve the issue.